# Why wont the Pi recognize my TV when I plug it in after boot?

Tags: raspbian, boot, hdmi, screen, display

Currently I am using a relatively new Westinghouse TV with my RasPi. It works perfectly with one caveat, I need to boot with it plugged in to the HDMI for it to work.

I run my Pi headless most of the time, but every so often I need to plug in the display to check things but when I plug in the HDMI while the Pi is running my TV does not detect any output.

Is there a command that I can run to make my Pi re-scan for devices?

I am running Raspbian.

I can post any other useful information upon request. (I don't know what to post that will help.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cec-client` seems to provide the functionality you need:

```
$ echo "scan" | cec-client -d 1 -s "standby 0" RPI
```

there's an explanation regarding installation and compilation of cec-client here: http://www.roberteklund.org/projects/raspberry-pi